# Aggregation with fuzzy filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Is possible in Elastisearch to have an aggregation which will have a filter/query including fuzzy?

ATM i have documents which contains nested object[]. What I want to achieve:

```
- select from each document 0..n nested objects which match a filter
- from this array of nested objects take the distinct one
- sort them by _score
- take the top 5 or X
- use the terms for an autocomplete/suggestions (should work more as a "like" and not autocomplete)
```

Until now I tried different types of aggregations like: significant_terms, top_hits but not in a good combination so I don't get the desired result.
Problems:

1. significant_terms doesn't return a value until he figures out when a term is significant (maybe i did not use a good analyzer)
2. top-hits returns any nested obj from the selected document and also contains duplicates

Here is an example of my query

```
  GET customerinsights/_search

    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "CustomerInsightTargets",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "CustomerInsightTargets.CustomerInsightValue": {
                        "query": "2017",
                        "operator": "AND",
                        "fuzziness": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } ,
  "aggs": {
    "root": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "CustomerInsightTargets"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_tags": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "CustomerInsightTargets.CustomerInsightSource.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_tag_hits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "_score": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "size": 5,
                "_source": "CustomerInsightTargets"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": "CustomerInsightTargets"
}
```